# Reliable, high performance radio link?

Tags: wireless

While connecting our small school to a new building, we're facing a problem: a tiny road splits "campus" in two, and we're not allowed to pass fiber cable over the street. Initially, we were planning to lay a 10Gbit fiber optic cable.

Are there any radio repeaters/antennas that can reliably keep the connection with an optimal quality grade? Distance between two points 8/10 meters. What costs, equipment and performance (speed & latency) may I expect?

Comment: Yes, you can! Anything _near_ the line-of-site path? See https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/204952224-airMAX-Planning-an-Outdoor-Wireless-Link then run https://link.ui.com/#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BlackBox](https://www.blackbox.co.uk/gb-gb/1587/Bridges) offers professional radio bridge links, but you are not limited to radio: A no-license-required infrared laser bridge can provide one or 10 gigabit/second of bandwidth as described at https://hackaday.com/2016/03/10/gigabit-ethernet-through-the-air/ , at http://www.koruza.net/features/ , and http://quickstart.koruza.net/ for less than two thousand Euros (VAT & freight not included).

Run a gigabit or 10 gigabit LAN connection to a point on walls which face each other. You can use power over Ethernet or bring out a 24VDC connection capable of 6W of power.

Mount a two kilo, 18 cm x 12 cm x 12cm, Koruza box on each wall.

[image: Diagram and photo of Koruza infrared laser optical bridge]

Align each laser to point at each other with the green laser included.

Then, turn off the aiming laser, and the eye-safe infrared laser in each Koruza box will connect through snow, dust, rain, and fog.

I would expect < 1ms latency per [this study](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328544938_Outdoor_Measurements_Using_an_Optical_Wireless_Link_for_Fixed-Access_Applications) .

Koruza is not the only vendor of **infrared optical laser bridges**, BTW; [BlackBox](https://www.blackbox.co.uk/gb-gb/page/22200/Solutions/By-Technology/Networking-Solutions/Wireless-Networking/laserlink-fso-and-rf-bridges) also offers professional grade infrared laser optical bridges as well as 60 GHz radio bridges, and [Ronja](http://ronja.twibright.com/models.php) offers a DIY 10 Mbps optical kit if you are have severe budgetary constraints.